# .swp swap files for directories while browsing with netrw

Tags: netrw, swap-file

Sometimes I browse around the directory of the current buffer by using `:Ex`. On one of my development machines, this results in a `.swp` file being created in every directory I visit.

I've checked the directory variable other machines where this doesn't seem to be the issue, and they match (`directory=.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp`).

I understand that `.filename.swp` files are useful for recovery and I would not like to disable swap files globally. The `.filename.swp` files are correctly cleaned up when buffers are closed.

I would be OK with this behavior for directories if the files were cleaned afterwords, but they linger... eventually I run `find -name ".swp" -delete` to clean them up.

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a netrw bug. You might be able to work around by creating a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` (create non-existent directories) and put in there `:set noswapfile`

Comment: Would this disable swapfiles for files being edited?

Comment: no, only for netrw buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Netrw normally sets noswf, which is a buffer-local option, for its own buffers.  However, if you have `let g:netrw_use_noswf= 0` in your .vimrc, then netrw won't set noswf, which may cause your problem.  What does `:verbose set swf?` show?

Comment: I went with Christian Brabandt's solution, so it shows "noswapfile last set from ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim"

Comment: if I remove the :set noswapfile, :verbose set swf? results in "  swapfile".